Power BI Multiply two columns regardless of filters applied
I have two columns 'ExpectedClaimsPerDay' and 'Number of Working Days' as shown in the image example below:

In Power BI, I want to multiple the two columns and I tried using the formula:
Expected Claims = ('Expected Claims'[ExpectedClaimsPerDay])*(SUM(Expected[Number of Working Days]))
However, This as you can see in the image is not giving me the correct results as it summing all the 'Number of Working Days'. I have tried using distinct but that breaks the visuals as there are multiple 'Movement Date (groups)' selected in the filter.
I want regardless of the filter applied, whatever is in 'Number of working days' without summing or anything, multiply whatever is in 'ExpectedClaimsPerDay'.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/4017932/michal @user:4017932 to break it down I have two tables 'Expected' and 'Expected Claims' they are joined on the column month, however, in table 'Expected', there is a column called Month week so each month is split into different weeks. Therefore, the data from table 'Expected Claims' gets split (repeated) into many. I don't know if this is the reason it is causing an issue. The formula you gave is giving an error as PBI is expecting some sort of aggregation for the column Number of working days, but I do not want to aggregate.I want the value how it is.

In addition, I tried using Expected Claims = ('Expected Claims'[ExpectedClaimsPerDay])*DISTINCT(Expected[Number of Working Days]) which works when the filter is only selecting one date but it breaks when selected multiple dates.

In your case, using SUM() on Number of Working Days is causing issues because it aggregates all the values across the filtered context, which isn't what you want. Instead, you want to multiply the ExpectedClaimsPerDay for each row by the corresponding Number of Working Days without aggregation.
What you are probably after (it's hard to say since your question is poorly worded and you didn't show us good examples of your desired outputs and inputs) is:
Expected Claims = 
SUMX(
    'Expected Claims',
    'Expected Claims'[ExpectedClaimsPerDay] * 'Expected Claims'[Number of Working Days]
)

